# Swift Realm querying by list property elements

Tags: swift, realm

I can't find anything similar in official docs and I wonder if it's possible. I got object:

```
class Post: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    let categories = List<Category>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Let's say, category contains objects with auto_inc id. I want to do query like select Posts where categories contain id 1, 4, 6. Is this possible, or do I need to write some 3-rd party filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely [possible](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering):

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let idsToFilter = [1, 4, 6]
let results = realm.objects(Post.self).filter("ANY categories.id IN %@", idsToFilter)
```